# Travelling from Indonesia to New Zealand

Tags: visas, transit-visas, australia, one-way

My husband will travel from medan Indonesia to New Zealand, but the ticket needed to transit in Singapore and Sydney.

Transit in Sydney for 3 and half hours.

My question is do my husband need to buy transit Visa for transit in Sydney?

Comment: To answer we need to know your husband’s citizenship and whether he has to reclaim his luggage in Sydney before checking in to his next flight.

Answer (score 0):

If your husband doesn’t clear immigration to collect bags and stays in the international transit area, he can transit without a visa.

The requirements for this are:

- Arriving in Australia by aircraft
- Have a confirmed onward ticket within 8 hours
- Have valid documents for that country
- must not need to clear immigration or leave the airport transit lounge for any reason before boarding your onwards flight

These requirements are listed on the [Australian home affairs website](https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/visas/getting-a-visa/visa-listing/transit-771/travellers-eligible-to-transit-without-visa).

Note: If you do leave the transit area to collect bags you will need to get a transit visa, unless you are visa free to Australia anyway (depending on your nationality and citizenship)